# windows phone 7 email like interface

Tags: email, interface, windows-phone-7

how do I create an interface where pressing on the left side brings up checkboxes as in email interface for wp7?

specifics

if you run the email application that comes with wp7 it has very nice feature

if you click on the left most side of any row (any message) then all of the rows/messages move to right and checkboxes appear on the left which can be checked for a group operation like deleting a bunch of emails at once.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight ListBox control?)
Each list item can be combination of controls or your custom control.
[See example on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265158%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)  Just put checkbox and label inside.

(maybe you should add more details in your question)